# uTorrent Automation using pywinauto

Tags: python, pywinauto, utorrent

I am trying out an utorrent automation using pywinauto lib. I want to add a torrent with URL. This option is under the file menu. I can get as far as opening uTorrent and then nothing happens. I used Swapy for generating this code. The box below opens only when I run the code in swapy. But when I save it into a file and run with cmd, only utorrent opens and a traceback occurs in the cmd.

[image: The Box where I want to enter the URL and Click OK]

```
from pywinauto.application import Application

app = Application().Start(cmd_line=u'"C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\uTorrent\\u Torrent.exe" ')
torrentdfb = app[u'\xb5Torrent4823DF041B09']
torrentdfb.Wait('ready')
menu_item = torrentdfb.MenuItem(u'&File->Add Torrent from &URL...\tCtrl+U')
menu_item.Click()

app.Kill_()

Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "AddTorrent.py", line 5, in <module>
torrentdfb.Wait('ready')
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 380, in Wait
WaitUntil(timeout, retry_interval, lambda: self.__check_all_conditions(check_method_names))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py", line 308, in WaitUntil
raise err
pywinauto.timings.TimeoutError: timed out
```

I am new to python coding and I am not an expert. It would be helpful if you provide the explanation to solve my problem or the code. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uTorrent is spawning another process, this is how I got it:

```
>>> app.windows_()
[]
>>> app.process
6096
>>> app.connect(title_re=u'^μTorrent.*(build \d+).*')
<pywinauto.application.Application object at 0x000000000405C240>
>>> app.process
4044L
```

This is a final code working for me (with 32-bit uTorrent and 32-bit Python 2.7):

```
import pywinauto

app = pywinauto.Application().start(r'uTorrent.exe')
time.sleep(5) # because method connect() has no timeout param yet (planned for 0.6.0)
app.connect(title_re=u'^\u03bcTorrent.*(build \d+).*')

main_window = app.window_(title_re=u'^\u03bcTorrent.*(build \d+).*')
main_window.MenuSelect(u'&File->Add Torrent from &URL...\tCtrl+U')

app.AddTorrentFromURL.Edit.SetText('some URL')
app.AddTorrentFromURL.OK.Click()
```

Bitness is important. 32-bit uTorrent crashes if I use 64-bit Python.

Comment: I don't know what happened but even my previous code doesn't seem to work. Now when I run the code, only utorrent opens and nothing seems to happen. When I check back the terminal, a traceback would have appeared. The traceback seems to be related to timeout. Even when I set the timeout to 10 or 15, the same error some up. I would be grateful if you could give me the full code. I'll look at it and learn what went wrong.

Comment: Obviously `menu_item.edit1.TypeKeys("url to enter")` is incorrect. Sorry, I have no time to write the whole script for you. And I cannot explain what's going wrong without tracebacks. Just edit your question if you wanna add more details.

Comment: I edited it. I added the traceback and put the exact code generated by swapy for clicking on the "Add Torrent from URL". When the code runs in cmd, utorrent opens and the traceback is given in cmd. Nothing else happens.

Comment: OK. Please check what `app.windows_()` returns when the window is open. Some applications spawn one more process, so probably `app.connect(title=u'\xb5Torrent4823DF041B09')` would help in this case.

Comment: [<pywinauto.controls.win32_controls.DialogWrapper object at 0x027DB770>, <pywinauto.controls.win32_controls.DialogWrapper object at 0x027DB750>]

Comment: OK, what's about `print [win.WindowText() for win in app.windows_()]`? And which one is expected to have a menu?

Comment: [u'GDI+ Window', 'Default IME']. The same traceback still occurs. I don't know which one has the menu.

Comment: OK, I found time to automate it on my side. The last assumption was true. It spawns one more process so we need to re-connect the `app` object by title (for example). See updated answer with the code.

Comment: Bitness is important. 32-bit uTorrent crashes if I use 64-bit Python.

Comment: Finally, it works!! Thank you for spending so much of your time.. Appreciate it!! Peace!!